# How to convert less than , greater than , equal < ,> ,= to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert less than , greater than , equal < ,> ,=  to SQL Server
Table Temp1
Data

```
--Condition--
less than
greater than
equal
```

```
Declare @Condition nvarchar(10)

SET @Condition = 
(SELECT CASE WHEN  Condition = 'less than' THEN '<' 
             WHEN  Condition = 'greater than' THEN '>'
ELSE '=' END AS Condition FROM Temp1 where Condition = 'less than')


IF (1 @Condition 2 )
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM Temp1 
END
```

Why is @Condition invalid?

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to do?  Especially what IF (1 @Condition 2 ) means?

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: The same reason `DECLARE @table sysname = N'foo'; SELECT * FROM @table;` is not valid. SQL Server can't evaluate programming elements and entities from variables - it doesn't do that in two passes like OO languages can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a big boolean expression:

```
if ( (@condition = 'greater than' and 1 > 2) or
     (@condition = 'less than' and 1 < 2) or
     . . .
   )
```

You could also do this using dynamic SQL, but you would still need a `case` expression to translate the words into symbols, so that would only add complication.